# How do I Set a Radio Widget's Choice Value in Django Template?

Tags: django-templates

I want to set each `value` of my radio buttons according to the widget choice (i.e., `option.pk` in forms.py). `{{ radio.id }}` produces None currently. How do I set each value using Django's template tags?

Daniel Roseman's answer here was helpful as usual ([Get the selected radio button in django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46689108/get-the-selected-radio-button-in-django-template#46689760)) and gave more information than in the docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/widgets/). 
However, I am unsure of how to set the value.

Template

```
{% for form in formset.forms %}
            <div>
                <div>
                {% for radio in form.selected_options %}
                    {{ radio.id }}
                    <label for="{{ radio.id_for_label }}">
                    <input type="radio" id="{{ radio.id_for_label }}" value="{{ radio.id }}">
                        {{ radio.choice_label }}
                    </label>
                {% endfor %}
```

forms.py

```
class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('question_text',)
        labels = {'question_text': ''}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QuestionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        OPTIONS = [
            (f'{option.pk}', f'{option}')
            for option in Option.objects.filter(question_id=self.instance.pk)
        ]
        self.fields['selected_option'] = forms.ChoiceField(
            choices=OPTIONS,
            required=True,
            widget=RadioSelect(),
            error_messages={
                'required': 'The question form lacks a selected option'
            },
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer regarding [the testing of the above code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56723817/2996101), `OPTIONS` will not be produced, unless the queryset used there, provided some results.

To achieve this, I have brutally modified the query just to show a succeeding scenario:

```
        OPTIONS = [
            (f'{option.pk}', f'{option}')
            for option in Option.objects.all()
        ]
```

Using the following views.py:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from my_app.forms import QuestionForm


class RadioView(FormView):
    template_name = "the/template.html"
    form_class = QuestionForm
```

And the following template.html:

```
{% extends 'admin/index.html' %}

{% block content %}
  {{ form.as_p  }}
{% endblock %}
```

The result is at least satisfactory.

You can extend it to use formests or to manually render the form as explained in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually).